# Not getting proper multiple array values

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am doing one project.In that project i am having some issues in multi arrays.
This (categ[0][category],categ[1][category],categ[2][category]) is dynamic.For refernce I am doing static..Select option is multiple

```
<select multiple name="categ[0][category]">
          <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
           </select>
            <select multiple name="categ[1][category]">
          <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
           </select>
           <select multiple name="categ[2][category]">
          <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
           </select>
```

> After POST,It shows only last value.(eg.)If I select 2,3,4 in
>   categ[0][category] and 1,3,4 in categ[1][category] and 2,3 in
>   categ[2][category] .It display only 4,4,3 these are selected last
>   values.
>
> this is my php code..

```
           $categ=array();$categ=$_POST['categ'];
foreach ($categ as $row)
{

    $ddd=array();echo $ddd=$row['category'];
    foreach($ddd as $ds)
    {
   foreach($ds as $fdfd)
   {
       echo implode(",",$fdfd);
   }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error??

Comment: No error,that is multiple selection,I am getting only last value in every selection..

Answer (score 1):

Remove one `foreach` in your code

```
$categ = array();
    $categ = $_POST['categ'];
    foreach ($categ as $row) {

        $ddd = array();
        echo $ddd = $row['category'];
        foreach ($ddd as $ds) {
            echo implode(",", $ds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No,now coming only last value,(means third select category last value.in above eg value is 3)..

Comment: According to your view, you will get only 1 value coz you have `categ[1][category]`, [2]...